# MS Access Validation Rule with Combobox

Tags: vba, validation, ms-access

I'm trying to setup a simple validation rule that will not allow someone to select the "Completed" option in a combo box unless it (The combobox field) is first set to "In Progress" which auto fills the Start Date Field.

It seems an iif statement is too complex. is there an easy way to setup a validation rule that will stop people from selecting completed if there is no start date?

Comment: Could have code modify the combobox RowSource so "Completed" is only available when appropriate. Or use combobox BeforeUpdate event to validate input.

Comment: I'd better create two fields: IsCompleted, IsProgressStarted, and created before /after update VBA handlers. Or you can just check correctness of values via error elicitation query, that checks values that are completed, but not IsProgressStarted

Comment: Yeah I've added an IF statement in VBA that restricts Completed to being changed only when there is a date in the Date Started. I was hoping for a simple validation rule but thinking back on it, this just made more sense.